# Error in Tutorial to sign-in to Google account using Python

Tags: python, google-plus, signing

This is a direct follow up to the information provided in this question:

- [Enter website by logging in Google Account using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174677/how-to-connect-to-a-google-account-using-python)

One of the suggestions I found, was to follow this google tutorial for python:

- [quick start for python](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/python)

And I am having some problems because of the heavy changes in the interface.

My biggest problem is in Step 1 - 3b. Aparently I have to paste these values:

```
http://localhost:4567
http://mysite.example.com
https://mysite.example.com
```

in some place, but I have no idea where.

So I simply continued with the tutorial, and launched the application on my localhost on port 4567.

Now, the application launched fine, but when I click the login button I get an error:

```
Error:invalid_client

no registered origin
Request details:

    scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.moments.write https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.agerange.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.language.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.members.read
    redirect_uri=postmessage
    state=303270744|0.3942616991
    origin=http://localhost:4567
    display=page
    request_visible_actions=http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity
    cookie_policy_enforce=false
    response_type=code token id_token gsession
    access_type=offline
    cookie_policy=single_host_origin
    proxy=oauth2relay678941372
    client_id=933139289991-iigr70l8u8rbjecm6vrrs3bj4fck0ptu.apps.googleusercontent.com
    authuser=0
```

Am I getting this error because the tutorial I am following is very outdated, or because I didn't do Step 1 - 3b correctly?

How can I fix this? All I want is to log in into a google account, if there is an easier way to do it with python, feel free to let me know :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the tutorial tells you how to set up the project using the Google API Console (see the link in Step 1, the first item), but Google is slowly moving people to use the Cloud Console instead. So if you follow that link, you get redirected to the new Cloud Console. If you want to get back to the API Console (so you can follow the rest of the steps listed there), you should see a message at the top of that page that says:

[image: Welcome to the new Google Cloud Console!]

If you click on the "Go back" link, you'll be back at the API Console and you can follow the rest of the steps listed in the tutorial.

Steps 1-3b are important, since they are how you setup a Project, indicate what API resources it has available to it, and indicate how you will be accessing the project. It also will give you the Client ID and Secret that your python program will use when connecting to Google's servers.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any tutorial on how to do it using the cloud console?

Comment: There is not, yet, since the Cloud Console isn't finalized. But you should be able to find most of the same features under `APIs & Auth` -> `Registered apps`