# Log into Google account using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to Sign into my Google account using Python but when I print the html results it doesn't show my username. That's how I know it isn't logged in.

How do I sign into google using Python? I have seen two popular modules so far for this urllib.request or Requests but none have helped me with logging into the giant Google.

Code:

```
import requests

# Fill in your details here to be posted to the login form.
payload = {
'Email': 'accountemail@gmail.com',
'Passwd': 'accountemailpassword'
}

# Use 'with' to ensure the session context is closed after use.
with requests.Session() as s:
p = s.post('https://accounts.google.com/signin/challenge/sl/password', data=payload)
# print the html returned or something more intelligent to see if it's a successful login page.
print(p.text)
```

Login form info:

```
<input id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Enter your email" type="email" value="" spellcheck="false" autofocus="">

<input id="Passwd" name="Passwd" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="">

<input id="signIn" name="signIn" class="rc-button rc-button-submit" type="submit" value="Sign in">
```

When I login the console will give me 4 link to request so I'm not sure if I'm even using the right URL.

```
Request URL:https://accounts.google.com/signin/challenge/sl/password
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 

Request URL:https://accounts.google.com/CheckCookie?hl=en&checkedDomains=youtube&checkConnection=youtube%3A503%3A1&pstMsg=1&chtml=LoginDoneHtml&service=youtube&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Fhl%3Den%26feature%3Dsign_in_button%26app%3Ddesktop%26action_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26next%3D%252F&gidl=CAASAggA
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 

Request URL:https://accounts.google.com/CheckCookie?hl=en&checkedDomains=youtube&checkConnection=youtube%3A503%3A1&pstMsg=1&chtml=LoginDoneHtml&service=youtube&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Fhl%3Den%26feature%3Dsign_in_button%26app%3Ddesktop%26action_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26next%3D%252F&gidl=CAASAggA
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 

request URL:https://www.youtube.com/signin?hl=en&feature=sign_in_button&app=desktop&action_handle_signin=true&next=%2F&auth=xAMUT-baNWvXgWyGYfiQEoYLmGv4RL0ZTB-KgGa8uacdJeruODeKVoxZWwyfd-NezfxB6g.
Request Method:GET
Status Code:303
```

I am currently using Python 3.4.2 & don't plan on using google's API.

Comment: I'd recommend OAuth over sending a plain-text password. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271110/python-oauth2-login-with-google

Answer (score 1):

This will get you logged in:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


form_data={'Email': 'you@gmail.com', 'Passwd': 'your_password'}
post = "https://accounts.google.com/signin/challenge/sl/password"

with requests.Session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get("https://mail.google.com").text)
    for inp in soup.select("#gaia_loginform input[name]"):
        if inp["name"] not in form_data:
            form_data[inp["name"]] = inp["value"]
    s.post(post, form_data)
    html = s.get("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox").content
```

If you save and  open the html in a browser, you will see the `Loading you@gmail.com…`, you would need Javascript to actually load the page. You can further verify by putting in a bad password, if you do you will see the html of the login page again.

You can see in your browser a lot more gets posted than you have provided, the values are contained in the `gaia_loginform`.

```
<form novalidate method="post" action="https://accounts.google.com/signin/challenge/sl/password" id="gaia_loginform">
  <input name="Page" type="hidden" value="RememberedSignIn">
  <input type="hidden" name="GALX" value="5r_aVZgnIGo">
  <input type="hidden" name="gxf" value="AFoagUUk33ARYpIRJqwrADAIgtChEXMHUA:33244249">
  <input type="hidden" id="_utf8" name="_utf8" value="&#9731;"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="bgresponse" id="bgresponse" value="js_disabled">
  <input type="hidden" id="pstMsg" name="pstMsg" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" id="dnConn" name="dnConn" value="">
  <input type="hidden" id="checkConnection" name="checkConnection" value="">
  <input type="hidden" id="checkedDomains" name="checkedDomains"
         value="youtube">
```

I am obviously not going to share my email or password but you can I have my email stored in a variable *my_mail* below, you can see when we test for it that it is there:

```
In [3]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [4]: import requests

In [5]: post = "https://accounts.google.com/signin/challenge/sl/password"

In [6]: with requests.Session() as s:
   ...:         soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?elo=1").text, "html.parser")
   ...:         for inp in soup.select("#gaia_loginform input[name]"):
   ...:             if inp["name"] not in form_data:
   ...:                     form_data[inp["name"]] = inp["value"]
   ...:         s.post(post, form_data)
   ...:         

In [7]: my_mail in  s.get("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox").text
Out[7]: True
```

Comment: I set variable my_mail = to my email and output returns nothing

my_mail = "fakemail@gmail.com"

Comment: The output could not possibly be nothing. Run the code exactly as posted creating the form_data dict as per the first code sample.

Comment: Check this picture of the code and tell me if you could spot what I'm doing wrong, it would be very appreciated http://imgur.com/lDgt8IM

Comment: @futurehendrix, you are not printing, `print(my_email in ...)`, unless you are running from a shell you need to print or you won't see output

Comment: added `print(my_mail in "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox")` and the output was false it failed to login

Comment: Not sure exactly what it is but you are doing something incorrectly, I have ran the code multiple times successfully, also you should receive a *"Did you just sign in"* email each time you run the code.

Comment: Does this still work in 2020? I tried, got a 200 response and the html just shows the login page.

Comment: Doesnt work unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google's OpenID connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect). Make sure when registering your application to define it as type "Desktop" and you are using "http://localhost" as the "redirect-uri". You should implement in your python script some code for receiving the redirection from Google authorization server. You can find a [working example here](https://github.com/controlthingsopensource/google-openidc)

Answer (score 0):

Except by using [oAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10271110/1658617) or their API, google has things like captcha and so to prevent bots from brute-forcing and guessing passwords.

You can try and trick the user-agent but I still believe it's to vein.