# Signing into Google Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to log into Google using Python 3.4.2.

I put my email in a variable called `my_mail` then searched for it and it returned false.

Yet Google sends me a "New sign-in" email. I clicked the this device is fine option but same results.

CODE:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

form_data={'Email': 'ExampleEmail@gmail.com', 'Passwd': 'Password'}
post = "https://accounts.google.com/signin/challenge/sl/password"
my_mail = 'ExampleEmail@gmail.com'

with requests.Session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?elo=1").text, "html.parser")
    for inp in soup.select("#gaia_loginform input[name]"):
        if inp["name"] not in form_data:
            form_data[inp["name"]] = inp["value"]
    s.post(post, form_data)

print(my_mail in "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox")
```

I tired debugging and it kept repeating these lines:

```
for inp in soup.select("#gaia_loginform input[name]"):
            if inp["name"] not in form_data:
                form_data[inp["name"]] = inp["value"]
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Google does not like to be scraped. They have APIs.

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from Google's API so I won't be limited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log into Google account using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540479/log-into-google-account-using-python)