# Python Log into Google using urllib

Tags: python, python-3.4, urllib

Before I start: I have already seen [Log into Google account using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540479/log-into-google-account-using-python) but I dont feel that it fully adresses my problem.

Ok, I didn't know how to best well word my anwser because the problem is actually quite complicated...

**Scenario:**

 I am developing a python application, and at one stage it has to very quickly attempt to login to google using urllib. It wouldn't be too hard to submit the form just normally, but the **(very likely)** issue arises that if they user has already logged in to google on this computer, then instead of the normal text boxes they see, they get the little form they can click on to choose their account. I will show you what I mean.[image: The choose account page]

Instead I want to be sure what appears will be the normal login page:
[image]

**Possible Solutions: (how would I implement these)**
1) When requesting the site, have some sort of "icongito mode" like you see in web browsers. If you launch in Icongito Mode, then the google does not show the accounts you are already logged in to.
2) Via a proxy, but then google may flag as suspicious.

So, this post was quite long, but if someone can give me a solution then it would be great. To wrap up: I want to access google via Python to log in, but I don't want google to show existing accounts.

**EDIT:**
Example Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


form_data={'Email': '****@gmail..com', 'Passwd': '******'}
post = "https://accounts.google.com/"

with requests.Session() as s:
    data = BeautifulSoup(s.get("https://mail.google.com").text)
    for inp in data.select("#gaia_loginform input[name]"):
        if inp["name"] not in form_data:
            form_data[inp["name"]] = inp["value"]
    s.post(post, form_data)
    html = s.get("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox").content
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of your code, and some idea of what you've tried? Also, in what environment are you working, are you calling this through a browser? Have you tried clearing cookies?And have you read through the Google API Docs? I would suspect they may have a flag or option in login API to handle exactly what you are attempting.

Comment: Interesting thing you have said about Google API, is there any wrapper for Python?

Comment: Absolutely. Google _loves_ Python, and have libraries for just about anything you can do on with Google.

Comment: Hope you find that useful. Oh, and generally, you shouldn't make comments  as answers. Something like 'I'll be using Google APIs' would be better addressed by simply editing your Question or adding a comment below it.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a link to Google's Python library for their APIs. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATE]
If you haven't found it yet, I *highly* recommend you look at this:

> https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/

I'd suggest first spending some time digging through their own API documentation:

> https://developers.google.com/

It would help to answer your question with some idea of the platform you are running this on. I suspect you aren't running into a problem with the machine having logged in before, but simply that you aren't clearing cookies from previous logins.