# Logging into Google account with Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

On multiple login pages, a google login is required in order to proceed. I would like to use `requests` library in python in order to log myself in. Normally this would be easy with the `requests` library, however I have not been able to get it to work. I am not sure if this is due to some restriction Google has made (perhaps I need to use their API?), or if it is because the Google login page requires the user to enter their email first, then press submit, and then enter their password, etc.

This problem has been asked before over here, but none of the solutions work for me. Currently I've been using code provided in this solution: [Log into Google account using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540479/log-into-google-account-using-python) as shown here:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

my_email = "email_placeholder@gmail.com" # my email is here
my_pass = "my_password" # my password is here

form_data={'Email': my_email, 'Passwd': my_pass}
post = "https://accounts.google.com/signin/challenge/sl/password"

with requests.Session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get("https://mail.google.com").text, "html.parser")
    for inp in soup.select("#gaia_loginform input[name]"):
        if inp["name"] not in form_data:
            form_data[inp["name"]] = inp["value"]
    s.post(post, form_data)
    html = s.get("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox").content

    print(my_email in s.get('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox').text) # Prints 'False', should print 'True'
```

As you can see the code at the end returns `False`. Furthermore, if I write the html to a file and open that in a browser, the page I get is the default Google login page indicating it has not worked.

Comment: I'm pretty sure google changes their methods time to time to stop people doing this, I imagine you'll have to do quite a lot of reverse-engineering to get this to work(and temporarily at that). I suggest checking [this](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/authenticate-users) out

Comment: One time i tried and gave up after noticing the class names in html are not always the same. One minute was one thing  and I reloaded and it had changed with an increment e.g. first time a class name somewhere could be myclass1, next time you reload myclass2, myclass3 etc and even the increments can randomly change :(