# What does the gidl query string parameter represent in the header of the 'CheckCookie' 302 redirect after authenticating to Google Cloud Console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, querystringparameter

I am trying to determine what the query string parameters represent after authenticating to Google Cloud Console.

It is the same when i log in to different GCP accounts and it is also the same when a friend logs into their GCP account however I noticed from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540479/log-into-google-account-using-python) that the gidl is different to mine and my friends. Does anyone know what this id represents?

Answer (score 1):

The [interface description language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_description_language) (IDL) is a language that allows unambiguous specification of the interfaces that client objects3 may use and
(server) object implementations provide as well as all needed related constructs such as exceptions and data types.

[IDLs](https://www.omg.org/spec/IDL/4.2/PDF) are commonly used in remote procedure call software. In these cases the machines at either end of the link may be using different operating systems and computer languages. IDLs offer a bridge between the two different systems.

This language use these interfaces or create the associated data types cannot be written in IDL, but in a programming language, for which mappings from IDL constructs have been defined.