# Authenticate user to retrieve Google Contacts in Python

Tags: python, google-contacts-api, google-oauth

I want to fetch Google contacts and for that I am following this doc. Here to authenticate user I am using OAuth 2.0 . But I am not able to authenticate my user .

```
    client_id = 'abcedf'
    client_secret= 'qwert'
    scope=(
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly'
        ),


credentials = {
  'client_id':client_id,
  'client_secret':client_secret,
  'scope':scope
}

auth2token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)
```

But above authentication is not working so I am not able to move forward to retrieve contacts .

[image]

Comment: This question will solved the problem of authentication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271110/python-oauth2-login-with-google/10546639#10546639

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Python to authenticate users, you can try and use the [oauth2client-library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#the-oauth2client-library) on how to use the Flow objects in authentication:

```
flow_from_clientsecrets()
```

The oauth2client.client.flow_from_clientsecrets() method creates a Flow object from a client_secrets.json file. This JSON formatted file stores your client ID, client secret, and other OAuth 2.0 parameters.

The following shows how you can use `flow_from_clientsecrets()` to create a Flow object:

**Using flow_from_clientsecrets()**

```
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
...
flow = flow_from_clientsecrets('path_to_directory/client_secrets.json',
                               scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
                               redirect_uri='http://example.com/auth_return')
```

**Using OAuth2WebServerFlow**

Despite its name, the `oauth2client.client.OAuth2WebServerFlow` class is used for both installed and web applications. It is created by passing the client ID, client secret, and scope to its constructor: You provide the constructor with a `redirect_uri` parameter. This must be a URI handled by your application.

```
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
...
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id='your_client_id',
                           client_secret='your_client_secret',
                           scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
                           redirect_uri='http://example.com/auth_return')
```